# How to change the 'Name' label on term add/edit pages programmatically?

Tags: 8, forms, taxonomy-terms

In Drupal 7 this was pretty easy. But now when I try to change the term name label on the term add/edit form all I find are protected methods.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'taxonomy_MYVOCABULARY_form') {
    ksm($form['name']);
    // ?????
  }
}
```

This is no translation issue.

Comment: Just a question, are you using multilanguage setup ?

Comment: @OlegVidenov - Single language. This is no translation issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you want to change the title of the form element, then it is basically the same as it was in 7.x.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'taxonomy_MYVOCABULARY_form') {
    $form['foo']['#title'] = t('New Title');
  }
}
```

Adding in what 4k4 said... field widgets behave differently than general form items:

```
$form['name']['widget'][0]['value']['#title'] = 'New Title';
```

Comment: Of couse, this was the first thing I tried. But it doesn't seem to be so simple anymore. At least in the term edit form.

Comment: If the field has a widget: `$form['name']['widget'][0]['value']['#title'] = 'New Title';`

Comment: @4k4 – It works but I wouldn't have excepted this as `ksm($form['name']['widget'][0]['value']['#title'])` only returns me some methods. None of them lets me set anything.

Comment: @leymannx, what you see is a translatable markup object, the result of the t() function. You can't change it, only replace it with a new `t('New Title')`.