# Where can I alter the labels used on the login form?

Tags: 8, forms

This must be configurable somewhere, surely, but I just can't find where. I'm sure I'm doing something silly. Apologies for such a simple question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the 'Name' label on term add/edit pages programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232272/how-to-change-the-name-label-on-term-add-edit-pages-programmatically)

Comment: The question mentioned as a duplicate is probably not quite a duplicate. It's the way I would do this as a programmer. The only out-of-the-box solution is to create your own localization.

Comment: I'll take a look at the localization option as a broader solution, thanks @mradcliffe. It's a surprise that Drupal would not have an interface for site builders to make such a change.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way by implementing [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.5.x).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function YourCustomModuleName_form_alter(&$form, Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
    if ($form_id == 'user_login_form') {
        //- change label for username input
        $form['name']['#title'] = t('Your New UserName Label');
        //- change label for password input
        $form['pass']['#title'] = t('Your New Password Label');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @berramou. Whilst it's workable and okay for a one-off it's not something I can offer to someone via the admin UI. It feels like Drupal core should have a non-code interface for all field labels really; this is quite an outdated approach from the point of view of a Drupal evaluator.