# Hook_form_alter for changing field labels doesn't work of user registration page

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working (in the below code, or other factors preventing the insert by the hook)?   I don't get an error message or page, the field labels are simply not overwritten...

I created my own module with the following hook on Drupal 8.5.7:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){

  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {

    $form['field_user_first_name']['widget']['0']['#title'] = 'First Name';
    $form['field_user_last_name']['widget']['0']['#title'] = 'Last Name';
    $form['field_user_phone_number']['widget']['0']['#title'] = 'Phone Number';
    $form['field_user_country_of_residence']['widget']['0']['#title'] = 'Country (of residence)';
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to change label take a loot at this question it's the same change just the form_id in condition and fields name: [alter the labels used on the login form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269563/where-can-i-alter-the-labels-used-on-the-login-form/269564#269564)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Simple Solution just change `['0']['#title']` by `[0]['value']['#title']`.

```
/**
 * @param $form
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 * @param $form_id
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
    if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
        $form['field_user_first_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#title'] = 'First Name';
        $form['field_user_last_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#title'] = 'Last Name';
        $form['field_user_phone_number']['widget'][0]['value']['#title'] = 'Phone Number';
        $form['field_user_country_of_residence']['widget'][0]['value']['#title'] = 'Country (of residence)';
    }
}
```

2. This solution a little bit complicated.
   After i test your code, i did some search, i found [this Post](https://knackforge.com/blog/karalmax/altering-labels-user-registration-form) say

   > It is apparent that we modify any form in drupal by implementing hook_form_alter(). But there are cases when even the hook_form_alter() cannot offer a solution in altering the form fields.

I tried to use [hook_element_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/8.6.x) as it suggested to alter fields.
In your case Here is the code bellow.

```
/**
* Implements hook_element_info_alter().
*/
function MYMODULE_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  if (isset($type['textfield'])) {
    $type['textfield']['#process'][] = 'MYMODULE_process_textfield';
  }
}
```

/**
* Process Callback Function
*
* Callback to process the User fields.
*/
function MYMODULE_process_textfield($element) {
  //- get the current route name
  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  if ($route_name == 'user.register' && isset($element['#array_parents'][0])) {
    switch ($element['#array_parents'][0]) {
      case 'field_user_first_name':
        $element['#title'] = 'New first name label';
        break;
      case 'field_user_last_name':
        $element['#title'] = 'New last name label';
        break;
      case 'field_user_phone_number':
        $element['#title'] = 'New phone numbe label';
        break;
      case 'field_user_country_of_residence':
        $element['#title'] = 'New country of residence label';
        break;
    }
  }
  return $element;
}

**Note** : all the four fields should be of type `textfield` `Text (plain)`, otherwise you should add another process to other `type`, see the example in the article for `password_confirm` type.

Answer (score 2):

following the link posted by @leymannx I clicked through to [another question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232272/how-to-change-the-name-label-on-term-add-edit-pages-programmatically), which had the solution somewhere in the comments.

I forgot to put **['value']** in the string, so it had to be :

```
$form['field_user_first_name']['widget']['0']['value']['#title'] = 'First Name';
```

I can confirm it works with both :

- ['0'] and [0]
- = t('first name') and = 'first name'

I doesn't work, at least for me, with omitting **['widget']['0']['value']**, as suggested in [alter the labels used on the login form – berramou](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269563/where-can-i-alter-the-labels-used-on-the-login-form/269564#269564)

Answer (score 0):

Try it without `[0]`, I don't think you need this.

---

**Edit**
Okay let me rephrase my words per @leymannx. I have tested the code on my machine and removing `[0]` solves the problem and updates the label text. I was providing an answer and was not asking for more information or anything from the author.

Answer (score 0):

In this approach, the hook is fired for all forms To avoid extra firing of the hook, use this approach (module name and form id)

```
function MYMODULE_user_register_form_alter(&$form, Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
  //do your alteration
}
```